# Set the path from an OpenFileDialog to a variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, variables, path

I have the following code to set the filename from a OpenFileDialog to a variable:

```
Dim OpenDLG As New OpenFileDialog
File = OpenDLG.FileName.ToString()
Dim xPath As String = File
        Dim ArrPath() = xPath.Split("\")
        Dim wPathLong = ArrPath(ArrPath.Length - 1)
```

But now I want to have the same for the Path. So: when a file is selected and set the path (without the filename) to a variable.

I tried to modify my existing code but I could not get it done.

How can I modify the code so when a file is selected and set the path (without the filename) to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetDirectoryName`. Sample code:

```
Dim OpenDLG As New OpenFileDialog
OpenDLG.ShowDialog()
Dim xPath As String = OpenDLG.FileName
Dim wPathLong = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(xPath) 'Bear in mind that it does not include an ending "\"
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than parsing the path yourself, it would be better, and easier, to use the methods in the `Path` class (in the `System.IO` namespace), for instance:

```
Dim filePath As String = OpenDLG.FileName
Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
Dim folderPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
```